# Values from a Range not coming up as an array

Tags: google-apps-script

I am unable to obtain an array from a getRange.getValues call to some data on a sheet, i.e. no brackets []. If I just create an array in the code I am OK. I am trying to use indexOf to locate a specific date. In my real code the date to match is also plucked from the sheet.
In the following test code the vars are global and not shown here.

```
function testArray() {
  var rowTwoDates = playgroundSheet.getRange(2, 59, 1, 5).getValues();
  var strippedRowTwoDates = rowTwoDates[0].map(stripTime);
  Logger.log('array:  ' + strippedRowTwoDates);
  Logger.log('indexOf:  ' + strippedRowTwoDates[0].indexOf("06/09/2022"));
  var scores = [10, 20, 30, 10, 40, 20];
  Logger.log(scores); // 2
  Logger.log(scores.indexOf(30)); // 2
}
9:38:23 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:38:24 AM  Info    array:  06/07/2022,06/08/2022,06/09/2022,06/10/2022,06/11/2022
9:38:24 AM  Info    indexOf:  -1
9:38:24 AM  Info    [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 10.0, 40.0, 20.0]
9:38:24 AM  Info    2.0
9:38:24 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: That's just a ui issue. To get proper logs, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(strippedRowTwoDates))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only checking `indexOf` for the first value in the array here:

`Logger.log('indexOf:  ' + strippedRowTwoDates[0].indexOf("06/09/2022"));`

I think you want to do this:

`Logger.log('indexOf:  ' + strippedRowTwoDates.indexOf("06/09/2022"));`

Comment: I am concerned that strippedRowTwoDates is NOT enclosed in array brackets as it should be from what I understand.

Comment: But I took your suggestion and it worked. I am still not understanding why it has no brackets like scores array.

Comment: I think it's because when you're printing it, it's not an array.

When you write this:

`"indexOf " + array`

You are forcing the array to turn into a string because you are adding it to another string. 

When you write `Logger.log(scores); `, you are not turning the array into a string, so it is displayed differently.

Type coersion is one of the things that people always criticise JS for.

To avoid this, write your logs like this:

`Logger.log("indexOf", array)`, then the two values are printed separately.